# How to fill transperent pixels of tiff file and keep geo information

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, pixel

I want to fill transperent pixels of a tif file which contain geodetic information (map) with black color.
When I open the file with photoshop for example I dont see transperent pixels, but when I open it with Geodetic system as "ArcMap" for example I can notice that some of the pixels are transperent.
Thats what I have try to do:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap bmp=null; 
    using(Image img =Image.FromFile(@"filelocation.tif")
    {
        bmp=new Bitmap(img);
        for(int y=0;y<bmp.Height;y++)
        {
            for(int x=0; x<bmp.Width;x++)
            {
                if(bmp.GetPixel(x,y).A!=255)
                {
                    bmp.SetPixel(x,y,Color.Black);
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
bmp.save(@"new file location ");
```

Results :

1)The number of pixel are the same but the size of the image is much smaller,why?

2)I have tried the condition ( Getpixel(x,y).A!=255) on a bmp file and it detected the transperent pixels , but  when I  execute the method on a tif file it doesn't detect the transperent pixels , Why ?

3)it doesnt matter if I execute this method on a 8\24 bit image it convert it to 24bit compressed image ,why thats happen ?

4)when I execute this method all the geodetic information disapper ,therefore the map is not longer map but a file without geodetic information ...
can I excute a method that just fill the transpert pixel with out generate a new file ?(in order to keep the geodetic information)

5)although I save the file in a tif format , when I look on the tif data ( with a tool called displayheader which represent the information about the file ) it seems like it converted the format to a png file ..., why that's happen ? 
Thanks!

Comment: 1) Do you mean the file size, or the image dimensions? 5) If there is no encoder for the original format, it defaults to PNG.

Comment: Hi , i mean the file size.

Comment: And how i find if the tif file has an encoder?

Comment: The file size is smaller because the original is probably an uncompressed TIFF, and it's replaced by a compressed PNG. The current image format might not be supported by the TIFF encoder, that would explain why it picks another. Try specifying ImageFormat.Tiff when you save it.

Comment: As a minimum change use : `bmp.Save(@"newFileName.tif", ImageFormat.Tiff);` Also do check the `PixelFormat` to be ideally `PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb`. If it is `24bpp` it doesn't event have transparency. Maybe posting an example image would help..

Comment: Hi , so I succeeded to locate the transperent pixels and fill them with the black color and save the file as a tif format thanks to yours recommendations ( bmp.maketransperent /imageformat.tif). But my original tiff is a 126mb uncompressed tif (rgb) , and when I execute my application it converts it to lzw compressed tif ( and weights about 60 mb)

Comment: How I save the new tif without the lzw compression ( save it as uncompressed 24 bit rgb ) ?

Answer (score 1):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap bmp=null; 
    using(Image img =Image.FromFile(@"filelocation.tif")
    {
        bmp=new Bitmap(img);

        bmp.MakeTransparent();

        for(int y=0;y<bmp.Height;y++)
        {
            for(int x=0; x<bmp.Width;x++)
            {
                if(bmp.GetPixel(x,y).A!=255)
                {
                    bmp.SetPixel(x,y,Color.Black);
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
bmp.save(@"new file location ");
```

Please add bmp.Maketransparent() function it will make transparent Bitmap image